# WIX: Can I set upgrade guid at time of installation through command prompt?

Tags: tags, wix, wix3.5

I want to set upgrade guid at runtime like:-

```
<Upgrade Id="[UPGRADEID]" />
```

and then set it at time of installation like

msiexec /i   ...\WiXWebInstaller.msi **UPGRADEID**="62718b57-574D-4A9A-A266-5B5EC2C02210"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no because of the following reasons:

- Try compiling a project the way you are trying it and you will hit the following error: **The Upgrade/@Id attribute's value, '[UPGRADEGUID]', is not a legal guid value.**
- Secondly, look up the description of the [Upgrade table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. The Upgrade element populates the Upgrade information for a particular Upgrade Code in the Upgrade table. The Id in your code snippet refers to the UpgradeCode column in the Upgrade table.

Looking at the description of [this column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can see that this column has a datatype of GUID. This means that you will have to use an actual GUID for the Id value. Had the datatype been **Formatted**, then you could have used the code snippet that you have pasted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx Kiran....It cleared the thought ...one more question ... Can I change upgrade Id at installation time ???

Comment: Hello, Are you asking if  you can change it once the installer is executed? I have never tried doing it but my guess is that it might just be possible.

Comment: Exactly , It is fine even if I could change the existing upgrade Id at installation time.....  secondly I also want to know If the same thing can happen with product name ?

Comment: Regarding Upgrade Code,  Yes you can.I have tried it earlier in a test project and i was able to do what you are asking.However, i wouldnt recommend doing so. Reason being, the Upgrade code is sacrosanct and is used at initialization for various operations in the msi package. Operations such as the ones required by the Upgrade table , detecting older versions of products etc all rely upon the Upgrade code.

Comment: No matter where you sequence your custom action to set the Upgrade Code, i suspect there are certain initialization routines in the windows installer engine which would make use of the Upgrade Code earlier than where you are setting its value.

Comment: I am not sure about the ProductName. Try it with a test project and you will know it yourself. I generally try things with a test project to make sure things work when in doubt.

Comment: I have tried giving product name at installation time by using property and by using customaction tag but did't work ..... Can give me some test code ?

Comment: Try making use of SetAProperty(Type 51) custom actions. Here is a code snippet(Modify it according to your needs)  <CustomAction Id="SetUpgradeCode" Execute="immediate" Property="UpgradeCode" Value="f630e5dc-95d8-40e1-b9eb-6fd349e30b5d" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="SetUpgradeCode" Before="AppSearch" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83500/discussion-between-keshav-and-kiran-hegde).